# Finding a specfic record in List And displaying 5 records above and 5 records below that record

Tags: java, collections, java-8

Trying to find a specific record in list and after that create a sub-list which contains 11 records i.e 5 records above selected record and 5 records below that records.

**Possible Scenarios**

- If selected list is the first record than only create sub-list with 5
  records below that record.
- If selected list is the first record and
  there are less records than 5 create sub-list with all records below
  that record.
- If selected list is the Last record than only create
  sub-list with 5 records above that record.
- If selected list is the
  last record and there are less records than 5 create sub-list with
  all records below that record.

Below is my current thought process surely more check will be added in this Approach,Is there a better way or any other suggestion

```
    int s = myList.indexOf(tests);
        if (s == 0) {
            if (s + 2 < myList.size()) {
                myList = myList.subList(s, s + 3);
            } else {
                myList = myList.subList(s, s);

            }

        } else if (s == 0 && s + 1 > myList.size()) {
            myList = myList.subList(s, s);
        } else if (s - 1 > 0 && s + 1 < myList.size()) {
            myList = myList.subList(s - 1, s + 2);
        } else if (s + 1 >= myList.size()) {
            myList = myList.subList(s - 1, s + 1);

        } else if (s == myList.size() - 1) {
            if (s - 2 > 0) {
                myList = myList.subList(s - 2, s + 1);
            } else {
                myList = myList.subList(s, s + 1);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out,

```
List<String> records = Arrays.asList("one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
        "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen");
final List<String> subRecords = IntStream.range(0, records.size()).filter(i -> records.get(i).equals("eight"))
        .mapToObj(i -> records.subList(Math.max(i - 5, 0), Math.min(i + 6, records.size())))
        .flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Notice I am using a `List` of `String` as a source records. Change it according to yours.

Alternatively the same can be done like so,

```
final int midIdx = records.indexOf("eight");
final int lowerBound = Math.max(midIdx - 5, 0);
final int upperBound = Math.min(midIdx + 5, records.size());
final List<String> subRecords = IntStream.range(0, records.size()).limit(upperBound + 1).skip(lowerBound)
        .mapToObj(records::get).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Update**

I have made the changes suggested by following comment, since it simplifies the code.

Comment: You first variant can be simplified using `records.subList(Math.max(0, i - 5), Math.min(i + 5, records.size())`. The second variant can be simplified using `.limit(upperBound + 1) .skip(lowerBound)`.

Comment: Thanks for the code review feedback ! I have changed the code as per your suggestions.